# NoReversematch Error In Django

Tags: python, django

I want to get an object by id, so when the user click on the title it will redirect the user to the page containing the id objects and I want my url link to be like this:

```
         http://127.0.0.1:8000/cripme/12/53-places-to-go
```

I tried the codes below but I'm getting this error:

```
  NoReverseMatch at /view_list/
  Reverse for 'cripdetail' with arguments '(1L, u'53 places to go')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Views for redirecting of users:

```
def cripdetail(request,fimcrip_id, fimcrip_title):
    post=Fimcrip.objects.get(id=fimcrip_id) 
    return render_to_response('postme.html',{'post':post, 'Fimcrip':Fimcrip},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

url:

```
url(r'^cripme/(?P<fimcrip_id>\d+)/(?P<fimcrip_title>[-\d\w]+)/$', 'meebapp.views.cripdetail', name='cripdetail'),
```

Template:

```
<a href= "{% url cripdetail Flup.id Flup.title %}" >{{Flup.title}}</a>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the title, not the slug. The title contains spaces which aren't accepted by your URL pattern. You should pass `flup.slug`.

Comment: I added flup.slug to the template but it's not working.Also I replaced fimcrip_title with fimcrip_slug. Still getting the same error. Can you please explain further?